# Bestselling products data is not gettting saved in its Table.

Tags: magento2.2.0, best-seller

I am using magento 2.2.0 and I am trying to fetch bestselling products, but the problem is that there is not even a single product in the `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly` table. As I purchased many products from it but none of them is saved in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Reports->Statistics->Refresh Statistics->Select all->Refresh Lifetime Statics->Submit